# strange behavior in copying array element to array in python

Tags: python, list

I'm facing a strange issue related to copying array elements inside other arrays, let me explain with a code:

I'm loading a csv into a bidimensional array, if I do something like this:

```
e = [None] * 4
with open("file.csv") as f:
    for line in f:
        e=line.split(",")
        finalarray.append(e)
```

If I do this, in finalarray I got only the last csv entry repeated all the time, but, if I do this:

```
 with open("file.csv") as f:
        for line in f:
            finalarray.append(line.split(","))
```

works like a charm, but I cannot undestand why the second option works and the first one fails loading always the last csv entry.

Kind regards, and thanks in advance.

Comment: both should work, although it would be better to use the csv module. Are you sure that this is your code? [mcve] please

Comment: There is no reason for both of these to behave differently. Probably you did something earlier which you failed to write here.

Comment: I suspect something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly

Comment: Nitpick: "into a bidimensional array" no, you are using a list that contains other lists.

Comment: Where's the array?

Comment: Key issue here: where is `finalarray` defined? Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score -2):

I think the problem is the e init.

We are using references to the same value, so, when you change the value, you change all the references. And the last value es the last entry in the CSV.

Comment: ... but you immediately discard `e` so it shouldn't matter.